# Film Scan Errors - Sprocket Holes Exposed to the Film

Tags: film, camera

I am a question regarding my film scans. I noticed that there are sprocket holes that are exposed to the film. I wonder if I did something wrong when I was rolling up the film to sent to develop, and whether I can fix this.[image: notice the sprockets that are in the scan]

Comment: What am I looking at, is this a crop of a scanned frame? I can see about six separate film strips!

Comment: Did you do the developing and then send the film out for the scan? When you ask about doing something wrong rolling up the film...didn't you simply rewind it back into the canister?

Comment: In order for us to know if you did something wrong we **need to know what you did** ! give us every detail from loading the film into the camera to sending in to get scanned.

Answer (score 2):

First -- Examine the film to verify that the film shows the same defects as the image from the scan. Likely a look will convince you that this is indeed an unwanted exposure (fogging) of the film to light or perhaps radiant energy like X-ray.

Assume fogging - likely when loading the film in the camera or removing the film from the camera. Also, the film may have been mishandled at the lab, exposed to light when loading the film onto the processing machine (reel etc.).

Could be a problem occurred during the developing of the film, such as a machine jam, and it was necessary to turn on the lights in the darkroom to solve the problem. First - look at the film and report what you see.